# Not able to add WishlistItem with same Product ID in a Wishlist (B2B Commerce)

Tags: commerce-cloud, connect-api, b2b-commerce, lwr, wishlistitem

For one of the B2B org, we have a requirement to add custom fields (Quantity__c and Product_Type__c) in the WishListItem object. With  [ConnectApi.CommerceWishlist.addItemToWishlist](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_CommerceWishlist_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_CommerceWishlist_addItemToWishlist_5)(), we can't set the values for custom fields, so we need to use the DML approach as below.

```
WishlistItem wishlistItemInput = new WishlistItem();
wishlistItemInput.Name='Item Name';
wishlistItemInput.Product2Id = '01t4K000000vzVnQAI';        
wishlistItemInput.WishlistId= '3or4K000000CjGVQA0';
wishlistItemInput.Quantity__c =1; 
wishlistItemInput.Product_Type__c= 'mobile';  
Insert wishlistItemInput;
```

The above code throws an error as below, if an existing WishListItem exists with same Product2Id under the specific Wishlist (WishlistId):

```
 System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, 
 duplicate value found: WishlistId duplicates value on record with id: 3os4K000000CfjIQAS: []
```

**Question:**
Based on the above code snippet it looks like "WishlistItem" object has some special handling, which prevents record insertion through custom DML when using the same Product2Id? Can someone from the Salesforce team or StackExchange community share if this is a known issue or if something missing in the above code?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

We raised a case with the Salesforce support team to check if the duplicate check for the same product2Id for a wishlist can be removed.

> According
> to our investigation it's not possible to remove the duplication check
> or to change the out of the box / default Wishlist functionality and
> it's objects and components, as they were designed to work this way.